# Continuity of additive functions- Boundedness

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I am trying to prove that if a function $f$ is additive and bounded for some nonvoid open interval $I$, then it is continuous at $0$.

To that end, I first proved that $f(rx)=rf(x)$ for $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. By using given information about $I$, we can say that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subset I$ for some $a$ and $\delta>0$. Since $f$ is bounded $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ implies that $\mid f(x)\mid\leq m$ for some $m>0$. By additivity
$$
f(x)=f(x-a)+f(a)
$$
so $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$ implies that $\mid f(x)\mid \leq m+\mid f(a)\mid=M$.

What I want to show is that we can choose $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $x\in (-\delta,\delta)$ implies

$$
\mid f(x)\mid=r\mid f(\frac{x}{r})\mid \leq r M
$$
and the final expression could arbitrarily be smaller, but I could not manage to write this clearly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For every $y\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ there is a rational $r$ such that
$ yr^{-1} \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$.
Then
$$
 |f(y) | = |r|\cdot|f(y r^{-1})|\leq |r| m.
$$

We also know that
$ |yr^{-1}-a|<\delta $
and therefore
$ |a| - |y||r|^{-1} <\delta$.
Thus $|r| < \frac{|y|}{|a|-\delta}$.

Combined, this results in

$$
 | f(y)| \leq |y| \frac{m}{|a|-\delta}.
$$

Now taking the limit $y\to0$ yields the result

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(-x)=-f(x)$ we may suppose wlog that $I\supset (a,b)$  with $0<a<b.$ Let $M=\sup \{|f(x)|:x\in (a,b)\}.$ We have $M\leq \sup\{|f(x)|:x\in I\}<\infty.$

Let $c=\min (a,b-a).$

For $x\in (0,c)$ take $k\in \mathbb N$ such that  $a<kx<b.$ Then $$|f(x)/ x|=|f(kx)/kx|\leq  M/kx\leq M/a.$$ Since $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=0,$ therefore $$\forall x\in (-c,c)\;(\; |f(x)|\leq (M/a)|x|\;).$$ So $f$ is continuous at $0.$